# When a notebook is put to sleep, will its battery drain quicker if more resources are being used at the time sleep is triggered?

Tags: battery

Assume the following:

1. A fully-charged laptop has multiple programs open - using a total of 8 GB RAM and 90% total of the notebook's overall CPU
2. The laptop is put to sleep directly from within Windows, and its power adaptor removed

In this example, would the battery run out any quicker than if less RAM was being used, and if the CPU use was much lower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put the pc to sleep, windows will keep the RAM active and suspend all processes. The RAM is not being changed, and all RAM has to remain powered for this to work, so it does not matter if you have very few programs open, or a lot.

CPU usage is suspended too, so in that regard nothing changes either.

The only thing that that consumes more power is the moment you go into sleep, and the moment you go out of sleep, as it has more functions to perform in order to prepare and resume from this state. So if you put the pc to sleep first, then remove the AC adapter, and put the AC adapter back in before you resume, the energy consumption is going to be the same.

That said, keeping the RAM active does require quite a bit of power on its own, but will be significantly longer than closing the lid, which will keep the programs active as well.

If you put the computer into hibernation, something else happens. The content of the RAM is written to disk and the pc is then turned off. At this point, no power is used at all, with the exception that a battery will simply drain on its own even though this is at a very low rate. Because the content is written to disk, it does not matter if the battery runs out or not. As long as there is sufficient power to start the machine and resume, it will work, even if that is a year later. Although if the clock desyncs a lot, it may actually prevent the computer to start, but that is for a completely different reason.